# how to prevent IE from caching get ajax request results

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, razor

i have the following inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
 <div class=" b" >Show   @Html.DropDownList("type", new SelectList(ViewBag.type, "Value", "Text", "" ), new { @id= "typeOptions",@class="SmallDropDown3"}) Requestors.
                        <img src="~/Content/sortloading.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progressSort3" /></div>  

@Html.Partial("_GetRequestors", Model)
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
        $("body").on('change', '#typeOptions', function () {


            $('#progressSort3').show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRequestors","Customer")',

                data: { id: "@ViewBag.AccountID", page: "1", type: $("#typeOptions").val() },

                success: function (html) {
                    $('#RequestorTable').html(html);
                    $('#progressSort3').hide(); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Which mainly display a dropdownlsit which will initiate an Ajax call when the list items changed. Here is the action method that will be called:-

```
 public ActionResult GetRequestors (int id = 0,int page=1,string type="")
        {
            int pagesize;
            ViewBag.type = ViewBag.PagedSizeOptions = new PageOptions().RequestorTypeOptions;
            bool succeed = int.TryParse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"], out pagesize);
           var aUser = repository.populateRequestorDetials2(id,type).OrderBy(a=>a.FIRST_NAME).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);

           ViewBag.AccountID = id;
           ViewBag.currenttype = type;
           if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
           {

               return PartialView("_GetRequestors", aUser);
           }
           return View(aUser);
  }
```

currently seems that IE will cache the result for a long time, and when changing the dropdpwnlist IE will always show the cached result for the same dropdown item, even doing a hard refresh (ctrl-f5) will not delete the cached result...
So i have mainly these two questions :-

1. for how long IE will keeps the cached data ?
2. I know that i can add cache:false as an ajax parameter . but the question is what  the default behavior if i do not specify any cache setting in my Ajax call for IE. as in chrome and firefox no cache problem will be faced?

can anyone advice on these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: what about to append a random uuid as url get parameter?

Comment: With Razor you should "fix" it server-side using various attributes on your action method. Most Ajax solutions will not be fine-tuned to server caching requirements (which you can have a lot more  control over on the server).

Answer (score 3):

1. The cache duration is specified by your server settings, not IE.
2. All browsers *should* cache the same way, but no guarantees.

Razor caching should be solved *server-side* as you have a lot more options and flexibility over what causes a request to cache or not (e.g. based on parameters changing).

The simplest option to stop caching is to add the following on a Partial View action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1)]
public ActionResult GetRequestors (int id = 0,int page=1,string type="")
```

This sets the cache to 1 second. 0 is not a valid option for partial views.

*Note: I am assuming you code returns a partial view. The options are different (simpler) for a full page view*

Comment: yes i know that i can define a caching profile and apply it to my action method, or to use cache:false inside the ajax request parameters . but my  question was for how long IE will keep caching the result , when i do not add any custom code to control the caching ?. you mentioned that the caching is specified by the server, so can you advice what exactly controls this ? is this inside IIs where i host my application ?

Comment: It is an IIS setting, which you can also override globally in your web.config. Just looking for a good reference for you now.

Comment: but why this caching setting did not affect Firefox and chrome ?. Because in my case i neither used "cache:false" as an Ajax parameter,  nor i added a cache profile to my action method. However Firefox and chrome will not cache anything even if i select the same dropdownlist item, while on IE it keeps using the cached data for long time (not sure for how long...). can you advice ?

Comment: so mainly i want to know what forced IE to cache the result even i did not specify anything to force browser cache as i mentioned before. so this raised a question on how long will IE keep caching the Ajax response ? and is there a way to control this ? . my question is not how i can enable/disable caching , what i am asking about is what control the caching for IE when no caching settings are defined as in my case?

Comment: @john G you are asking the same question over and over again and receiving the same answers. In my comments I answered why. I also answered how long (however long it feels like caching). Controlling the caching is enabling and disabling the cache, the only other setting you can control here is the time there are a few methods to cache, most explained here. What value are you not getting out of these answers/discussions?

Comment: @har0ld so are you saying if i keep the current setting of not specifying any caching, then IE will keep caching the Ajax response forever?

Comment: @johnG IE is a black sheep. When it comes to this kind of thing its behaviour is unpredictable at best. You are better off specifying full server-side caching rules. As far as I have gone with experimentation, ETags work well with IE but they are a bit of a performance hit for the server. If performance is too important then the only option you really have is detecting IE and using the `cache: false` flag. IE changes its caching per version and operation mode so most people haven given up. Pretty much no other browser behaves in this manner.

Comment: @har0ld but why you want me to check for IE and use cache:false accordingly ? since other browsers will not cache anything if no cache settings were specified. so i can define cache:false without the need to check for IE , if i do not want to have caching? did i understand your point ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to prevent caching.

**Example**

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Or if you just wanted it for that request you could:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("GetRequestors","Customer")',
        data: { id: "@ViewBag.AccountID", page: "1", type: $("#typeOptions").val() },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#RequestorTable').html(html);
            $('#progressSort3').hide(); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't remember.. does jQuery do the legwork to make this safe for URL's with query strings in them?

Comment: @har0ld From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options `It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.`

Comment: Yeah that's what I was talking about. But is jQuery smart enough to work out if the URL already has a query appended? I only ask back OP is using razor and there is a possibility (I am pretty sure) that the URL builder can put it's own query on the end of the URL.

Comment: @ColinBacon my original question is not about how to disable caching.,, i was asking for how long IE will keep caching the data when i do not specify cache:false, and what controls this  ???

Comment: @har0ld what do you exactly mean by "does jQuery do the legwork to make this safe for URL's with query strings in them"?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"?" + (new Date()).getTime()` to the end of your URL.

i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetRequestors","Customer")' + "?" + (new Date()).getTime(),

            data: { id: "@ViewBag.AccountID", page: "1", type: $("#typeOptions").val() },

            success: function (html) {
                $('#RequestorTable').html(html);
                $('#progressSort3').hide(); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.

            }
        });
```

Comment: but if i do not add any extra code to manage the cache,, for how long IE will kepp using the cached data ?

Comment: @john G I know this is a rather vague and negative answer, but as long as it feels like it. IE doesn't play nice with caching and proxies so if there is an instance where a proxy is doing the caching, it does not seem as though IE respects etags and such. The best bet for high changing data (more frequent than a couple days) is to use the time parameter. It is a scrappy hack, but something we have to deal with. If anyone wants to share anymore light on this, feel free

Comment: but my question was if i do not specify any thing to control the cache , then for how long IE will keep retriving the cached result for the ajax request ?